# var_dump not printing the integer values

Tags: php, membase

I am trying to read some values from the membase.
I observer that when there is any integer the following command is not working.

```
 var_dump($memcache->get("keyset123"));
 print_r($memcache->get("keyset123"));
```

If the get result is a string the above command prints.
If the get result is a Integer the above commands are printing none.

vardump prints =string(0) ""
print_r prints none.

can you please tell me what is the issue

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `$memcache->get()` call is returning a string value.  Your problem lies elsewhere (likely deeper within the code in use), not within `var_dump()`.

Look into what you're storing within whatever is inside of the variable $memcache.

Comment: I am using the basic function to get .

Comment: I agree it could may not be issue with the var_dump().

Comment: But I am not getting what I am missing in the membase, get function. can you please help me in that regard

Comment: $memcache->get() always returns string. will that be an issue not printing the value?

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/memcache.get.php yep, only returns strings...which means you need to know when you're supposed to be storing as strings, and typecast to integer or float appropriately.  Again, verify what you're storing inside of the memcache and see what it is going in.

Comment: I tried different permutations that I know I stil see the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($memcache->get("keyset123"));
//outputs
//string(0) ""
```

Memcached is storing an empty string at the key "keyset123", otherwise you would be getting FALSE (key doesn't exist) or NULL (key exists, but no value exists)

Comment: James, keyset123 is having a integer value in the database. why am I not able to get that value? If I keep the value as string it works